# android relative layout not working properly

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to do a row for a recyclerview, row will be splited in 3 columns

1. First - Image Button
2. Second- Content (textviews)
3. Third - Image Button

and when i load a huge content, it make the layout to grow, and its ok, but i want the side panels to grow in height too:

what i want(And Android Studio SHOW that will be (liar =( )):

[image]

and what i really got:

[image]

and my row.xml is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/thebig_father_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">


      <RelativeLayout
          android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          android:id="@+id/i_must_grow_in_height"
          android:layout_width="48dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
          <TextView
              android:text="Grow and to center!!!!"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
      </RelativeLayout>



      <RelativeLayout

          android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/i_must_grow_in_height"

          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/relativeLayout4">

          <LinearLayout
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

              <TextView
                  android:text="Im the content i can grow in height but the side panels must GROW TOO"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

              <TextView
                  android:text="Im the content i can grow in height but the side panels must GROW TOO"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

              <TextView
                  android:text="Im the content i can grow in height but the side panels must GROW TOO"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

              <TextView
                  android:text="Im the content i can grow in height but the side panels must GROW TOO"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

              <Button
                  android:text="Random Content"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
              <Button
                  android:text="Random Content"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
              <Button
                  android:text="Random Content"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
              <Button
                  android:text="Random Content"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
              <Button
                  android:text="Random Content"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
              <Button
                  android:text="Random Content"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


          </LinearLayout>
      </RelativeLayout>



      <RelativeLayout
          android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
          android:layout_width="48dp"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"

          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4">

          <TextView
              android:text="C'mon i need it too"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

      </RelativeLayout>

  </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

someone can explain WHY its not growing(the red Layout) ?

Comment: Could you show us how do you show this layout? just with setcontentview?

Comment: add center in vertical  is true in relayoute layout. I hope its work.

Comment: @NikoYuwono yep, nothing special just -> ```View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.mynew_textview, parent, false);```

Comment: Where are you experiencing the problem? Device/emulator, Android version etc? I copy pasted your code and it looks fine at a 4.4.2 device.

Comment: @SwagataAcharyya at LG G4

Comment: @Destro the red moved to middle but not growing up not even down =/

Comment: red color are set relative backround..

Comment: Did you try testing in another device?

Answer (score 2):

In those layouts where you have used

`android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"`

Make their height auto adjusted according to the content not to the container's height.

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

and if you want image-Buttons to go Red from the beginning then try height of textView inside that red color RelativeLayout as match_parent.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@color/Red"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="C&apos;mon i need it too" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Screenshot of my LG OG(4.1.2).

[image]
  Here is full XMl, very minute changes , i think you should clean project and try on other device or emulator...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/thebig_father_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/Blue" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/i_must_grow_in_height"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@color/Red"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Grow and to center!!!!" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/i_must_grow_in_height"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/relativeLayout4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/i_must_grow_in_height"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/relativeLayout4"
        android:background="@color/Blue" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Im the content i can grow in height but the side panels must GROW TOO" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Im the content i can grow in height but the side panels must GROW TOO" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Im the content i can grow in height but the side panels must GROW TOO" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Im the content i can grow in height but the side panels must GROW TOO" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Random Content" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Random Content" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Random Content" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Random Content" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Random Content" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Random Content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@color/Red"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="C&apos;mon i need it too" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

The **row.xml** code you have posted is working for me? check if you have multiple row.xml files in your project under different density etc. (included modules/libraries). One way to check this easily is to hover your pointer above the **R.layout.row** in your Java code and click while holding Ctrl. This will give all places where this row.xml file exist.

View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()) .inflate(**R.layout.row**, parent, false);

I would suggest using less nested views, and this can be done with a LinearLayout as well:

**RelativeLayout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButtonOnLeft"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:contentDescription="info button"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info"
    android:text="Grow and to center!!!!" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButtonOnLeft"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButtonOnLeft"

    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButtonOnRight"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageButtonOnRight"

    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Im the content i can grow in height but the side panels must GROW TOO" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Random Content" />

</LinearLayout>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButtonOnRight"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:contentDescription="dialer button"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_dialer"
    android:text="C'mon i need it too" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**LinearLayout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
android:orientation="horizontal">


<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButtonOnLeft"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:contentDescription="info button"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info"
    android:text="Grow and to center!!!!" />


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Im the content i can grow in height but the side panels must GROW TOO" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Random Content" />


</LinearLayout>


<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButtonOnRight"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:contentDescription="dialer button"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_dialer"
    android:text="C'mon i need it too" />


 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: awesome thank you, maybe the problem was a lot of nested panels, can you just explain why    in LinearLayout     ```android:layout_width="0dp" and weigh=1? ```

Comment: Quoted Lint Warning: "When only a single widget in a LinearLayout defines a weight, it is more efficient to assign a width/height of 0dp to it since it will absorb all the remaining space anyway. With a declared width/height of 0dp it does not have to measure its own size first." check out this answer for more on the weight attr: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean